# Having business pages in different languages

Tags: facebook

I deal in books in different languages. I want to set up Facebook buisness page with multiple pages. Each page will be country specific and has to be in a local language. I have created 2 pages, in english and french but when I change form one language to the other it changes on the other as well.

Is it possible to delink and retain separate languages for each individual page.